# UPDATE the same way as INSERT using VALUES?

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if I can use UPDATE without explicitly stating column = value. Something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value, ...);
```

The reason I need this is that I'm getting the columns and values from an array and it's dynamic for different tables with different column names and different amounts of columns, so I want to accomplish something like this in NodeJS:

```
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ${t_name} WHERE ${Primary_key} = ${Primary_key_value)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ${t_name} (${cols})
        VALUES (${inputs})
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    UPDATE ${t_name} SET (${cols})
        VALUES (${inputs})
    WHERE ${Primary_key} = ${primary_key_value)
    END
END
```

Which is essentially replacing a row that has some id with a new row having the same id.
Is there a way to accomplish something like that?

Comment: Pretty bad idea: write separate commands for each table, don't bodge dynamic SQL together just for the sake of DRY

Comment: @Charlieface I have to do the exact same thing for like 20 tables, I don't see the logic of writing 20 different queries. I've actually managed to do what Dake K suggested with cross apply. but if you can explain why not do it I would love to hear more

Comment: Because you are injecting SQL directly into a query and that is not usually advised, and what will you do if for example the table has multiple primary key columns? I hope that you are not getting the table and column names from user input, and that the actual data is at least parameterized. Also see [Aaron Bertrand: Please stop using this UPSERT anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern) for how to make your upsert much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you use `CROSS APPLY`. I don't follow the way you are building the query, but here is the raw SQL update:

```
UPDATE T SET
    Col1 = X.Value1
    , Col2 = X.Value2
FROM MyTable T
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Value1','Value2')) AS X (Value2, Value2)
WHERE T.id = @Id;
```

Comment: hey thanks, can you elaborate on your example of usage of multiple columns and values? I didn't quite get how to apply it. What is Col1 = X.Col1 doing essentially? and do I still need to explicitly state how many columns I'm modifying? I've edited the placeholders to be more clear

Comment: Done... `Col1 = X.Col1` (I've changed to `Col1 = X.Value1`) is assigning the static value1 to column1 of your table. You'll have to build those string, but its not much harder than what you are already doing.

Comment: ok, I get it now, thanks. so I do need to state col1 = x.value1... for each column in the table. I guess I need to find a way to dynamically do it to match each table it will be used on

Comment: Yip - thats the basic `update` statement - you can't change that. You've already got a list of columns, so its fairly simple string manipulation to build the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need an explicit `cross apply`.  Just use:

```
UPDATE T
    SET Col1 = V.Value1,
        Col2 = V.Value2
FROM (VALUES ('Value1','Value2')) V(Value2, Value2)
WHERE T.id = @Id;
```